# Clipping raster image using mask layer is not clipping in correct way

Tags: qgis, masking

I am using QGIS 3.10 when tried to clip raster with mask layer I got the same result of extent layer knowing that I activated option with extent boundary

[Link for shapefile and raster](https://we.tl/t-KmqGvnhIEW)